# Logical bit-wise AND of two boolean instant vectors on PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm trying to define the E2E access availability of a service from a user PoV as the result of applying the **bit-wise AND operation** between two boolean instant vectors representing individual service availability.

I'm fetching the `probe_success` results of pinging these two services (e.g. S1 and S2) from a "user node" with the `blackbox_exporter` preinstalled:

```
            +-------+     +---------------------+     +-------+
            |S1     |     |                     |     |     S2|
            |       |     |   User node with    |     |       |
            |       +<----+  blackbox_exporter  +---->+       |
            |       | icmp|                     |icmp6|       |
            +-------+     +---------------------+     +-------+
```

Since the targets are probed using different modules (icmp and icmp6) I'm using two jobs and therefore getting two instant vectors:

```
probe_success{job="S1", user="foo"}
# AND
probe_success{job="S2", user="foo"}
```

As I read on [Prometheus (querying) logical operators docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators), that logical `and` is not exactly what I'm looking for. ¿Is there an easy way to perform these kind of "bit-wise" operations in PromQL?

Answer (score 3):

Because the cardinals between `probe_success{job="S1", user="foo"}` and `probe_success{job="S2", user="foo"}` are not the same, the logical `and` operator will not result in a vector/scalar with your desired effect.

There is no less complex way of achieving it. I would use something like this:

```
(scalar(probe_success{job="S1", user="foo"}) + scalar(probe_success{job="S2", user="foo"})) == bool(2)
```

`scalar` converts the single element input vector into a scalar. `probe_success` handily is a single element input vector, if absolute cardinals are used. For example, the same expression will not work if used with `probe_success{user="foo"}` as it will result in multiple element vectors.

`+` operator obviously adds the two scalars

`bool()` is used because Prometheus expects that the bool modifier must be provided between 2 scalars to be compared, in this case with a `==` operator. [Refer](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators) here about this.

Comment: Awesome; this is basically what I was trying to do. However since this will result in a scalar itself; not an instant vector - I cannot apply aggregation operators like `avg()` to get the average SLA of the joint service. Tthe graph view shows the time series I'm trying to average https://i.imgur.com/0ZwTo4D.png - any way to put all these results back into an instant vector?

Comment: One approach would be to use [Recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/). With this, you can add any labels as part of the rules, which will result in a vector. Not sure if that is what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: It is indeed what I'm trying to achieve - but **since `scalar()` drops all the original labels** form `probe_success`. I'd need to define one recording rule per `user`. Isn't that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.. but I'm sure there are better ways around depending on your particular case

Answer (score 1):

A subtle variation to preserve the labels:

```
sum(probe_success{job~"S[12]", user="foo"})by(user)== bool(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

The [`and` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) can be used for this task in the following way:

```
(probe_success{job="S1", user="foo"} == 1)
  and ignoring(job)
(probe_success{job="S2", user="foo"} == 1)
```

It uses `ignoring()` modifier for ignoring the `job` label when searching for pairs of time series with the same set of labels on the left and the right side of `and` - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for details.

It has the following advantages comparing to other methods:

- It preserves all the labels for `probe_success` metric.
- A single query can be used for returning success probes across multiple users:

```
(probe_success{job="S1", user=~"foo|bar"} == 1)
  and ignoring(job)
(probe_success{job="S2", user=~"foo|bar"} == 1)
```

or across all the users:

```
(probe_success{job="S1"} == 1)
  and ignoring(job)
(probe_success{job="S2"} == 1)
```